# Tiny 0.33 F Capacitor

Tags: identification, electrolytic-capacitor

I need to replace these (what I think are) capacitors, but the rating seems very high. They are smaller than the tip of my finger, yet the label pretty clearly says 0.33F, 5.5V. This seems wrong, as in my experience, even caps in the range of 100's of μF are physically much larger. A precursory search on DigiKey doesn't show  anything similar. Is this some type of special capacitor, or not even a capacitor at all?

[image: The Cap] 
 [image: The rating]

Comment: It is a super cap

Comment: Typing "0.33f 5.5v 10mm" into Google finds several reputable distributers that sell similar parts. Product recommendations are however off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what's known as a [Supercapacitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercapacitor).

They have specialized uses, most commonly as energy storage for real-time clock/calendars or retaining data when the power is off or the main battery is being changed.

Comment: Yeah, thats exactly what it was being used for. Thanks a lot.